# Debug angular 6 app build with cli and hmr in vs code and chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, webpack-hmr

Debugging with vs code and angular (2/3/4/5/6/7) application running inside chrome built with cli and having hmr (hot replace) enabled does not seem to work as expected.

Initially, when the app launches everything works perfect but after the first hmr replacement break points don't hit (get misplaced) and source code get mixed.

Same thing happens if you try to debug inside chrome too.

Is there a way to make it work?